# Creating snap node from intersections in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I created a straight line using the freehand line tool, and then from the end of the line, using the snap-to-node feature, I created a circle using the ellipsis tool. This means the center of the circle is exactly the end of the line.

[image]

I now want to create a node at the intersection of the line and the circle, so that I can start drawing more lines starting exactly from that intersection point.

Is it possible to dynamically create a node through intersected lines? This doesn't need to be specific to circles and lines. I'm also wondering if I have two intersecting lines drawn by the freehand line tool, how can I break them apart so that each intersection point becomes a node?

Answer (score 11):

1. In the Snap Controls bar, enable the following snapping options:

   - Enable Snapping
   - Snap Nodes, Paths and Handles
   - Snap to Path Intersections
   - Snap Cusp Nodes, inc. Rectangle Corners
   - Snap Other Points
   - Snap an Items Rotation Center
2. Draw the circle, and the line.
3. Move the line over the circle until the Cusp Node for the centre shows, and drop it there.
4. Select the line with the Nodes tool.
5. Mouse over the intersection of the line and circle until the "Handle to path" indicator shows
6. Double click it to add a node.

[image]

7. To break apart a path at a node, select the node with the Nodes tool, and hit the Break Path at Selected Nodes icon in the toolbar along the top.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this works. At step 5, I don't see the "Handle to Path" appearing when I hover over the intersection. When I watch the animation, I think you are clicking on the circle first, and then line for some reason at step 5. I couldn't exactly figure out what you did there.

Comment: Apologies, I missed out a snapping option - *Snap to Path Intersections*. I've edited the answer with the extra step.

Comment: Thanks, it still didn't work for me, but I figured it out because I had to draw a Bezier curve. Now, this works. :) I was drawing a freehand line tool. Is this because what I draw with the freehand tool is not a path?

Comment: No, the Freehand tool also draws paths, the Pen tool is more accurate  when you want to control curves, or draw perfectly straight lines, or place nodes accurately.  It might be best if you familiarise yourself with the various tools in Inkscape before you try more complex work. I had assumed you already knew the basics.

Comment: I know this is old but with handle to path shown the double click does not put the node at the intersection it puts it off intersection relative to the mouse position.

Comment: Okay, all sites say this will work.  The trick is you need to be zoomed out, if you are zoomed in too much it wont snap....

Comment: @old_timer You are correct. Looks like you may have discovered a bug in the newer (1.2.x) versions. Should probably be reported to the developers. You shouldn't have to zoom out for the node to snap to the intersection.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding my answer to this 3-year-old post because it's 2020 and neither Google or Inkscape's help forum can give me a clear answer to the problem within the 3 top results.

Solution:

1. Do everything Billy Kerr says, up to and including Step 3.
2. Select the circle, then go to Path > Object to Path. This must be done because as long as the circle remains an object, the circle's own top handle *might* interfere with Inkscape's ability to trigger the "Handle to Path" indicator - even if you send the circle to the bottom by pressing your "End" key.
3. Follow steps 4 - 6, then 7 if desired.

Also, as Kerr stated, beziers are much better than freehand for accuracy. However, whether you use bezier or freehand to draw a verticle or horizontal line is irrelevant, as long as you hold down your Ctrl key while drawing the line.